# Adding new references each time a new Google sheet is created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google spreadsheet, there is one Master sheet that includes cell references to Student sheets in the same spreadsheet. Each Student sheet includes a lot of data but only 10 cells of data need to be referenced in the Master.

I can easily set up references in the Master to the existing Student sheets but need to write a script where upon each new sheet creation, the next empty row in the Master sheet is populated with cell references to that newly created sheet.

So, a couple rows in the Master might include these formulas:

```
        A                       B                       C
------------------      ------------------      ------------------
=StudentSheet**01**!A1  =StudentSheet**01**!B1  =StudentSheet**01**!C1

=StudentSheet**02**!A1  =StudentSheet**02**!B1  =StudentSheet**02**!C1
```

Since I cannot pre-populate all the possible Student sheet references, since they don't exist yet, I think I need a script that will add a subsequent row to the Master, that includes the name of the new sheet and the cell references.

I probably also need to specify the first empty row in the Master, which may require calculating the count of data in a column and then adding one -- unless their is a method or function that goes to the next empty row automatically.

I tried some things with import range but my need is a push, instead of a pull.

Any ideas to get me started would be great.

Thanks!